# I want to create a login page using servlets

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I want to create a login page using Servlet & JSP.

I ve created a page which gets Username & password.

I made a database with a table which contains Username & password.

```
<form action="LoginPage" method="POST">
    User name: <input type="text" name="userName" size="20"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="20">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I entered the below code in doPost()

```
 response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName").toString();
    String passWord = request.getParameter("password").toString();
    Connection con = null;
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "userdb";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String user = "root"; 
    String password = "1234";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName, user, password);
        PreparedStatement pstmt;
        String sql = "SELECT USR_NAME FROM LOGIN WHERE USR_NAME='userName'";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
        String usr = null;
        String pass = null;
        while(rs.next())
        {
            pass = rs.getString(3);
        }
        if(pass != null && pass.equals(passWord))
        {
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Login Sucessfull</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Login Sucessfull " + request.getContextPath () + "</h1>");
            out.println("<p>Welcome</p> " + userName);
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");

            out.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Login is not Sucessfull</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Login is not Sucessfull " + request.getContextPath () + "</h1>");
        out.println("<p>Wrong Username Or Password</p> ");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        out.close();
```

And I dont know how to make it work.
Any Quick Fix Available For me?

Its not a big project, i jus want a Login page which gets username & password 
then the servlet will search the username in DB then checks for password.
I have made the changes you guys told. **But the output looks like something
wrong in try block, Because, I get the Login not successful page. 
I put the code "Login not successful Page" in Catch block.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unclear what you mean with "How to make it work". What happens? What happens not? At least I can spot several problems in your code:

1. You are emitting HTML inside a servlet. You should use JSP for this.
2. You are leaking JDBC resources. You need to close them in `finally`.
3. You are not setting the *entered* username (and password) in the SQL string.
4. You are not letting the DB do the task of comparing the password. Add it to the `WHERE`.
5. You are swallowing the exception. All detailed info about the problem cause get lost. You should either rethrow it as `ServletException` or at least log the exception type, message and cause. This information is important since it tells something about the root cause of the problem. You know, once the root cause is **understood**, the solution is *obvious*.

Further it's also bad user experience if you change the page to a page where the user can do absolutely nothing else than facing an error message. The user has to take extra handling to go back to the login page to re-enter the details. Rather redisplay the same page with the error message inlined.

Rewrite your `doPost()` method as follows:

```
String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
String passWord = request.getParameter("password");

String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String dbName = "userdb";
String user = "root"; 
String password = "1234";
String sql = "SELECT * FROM LOGIN WHERE USR_NAME = ? AND USR_PASS = ?"; // Not sure how the password column is named, you need to check/update it. You should leave those ? there! Those are preparedstatement placeholders.

Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
boolean login = false;

try {
    Class.forName(driver); // You don't need to call it EVERYTIME btw. Once during application's startup is more than enough.
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, user, password);
    statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    statement.setString(1, userName);
    statement.setString(2, password);
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
    login = resultSet.next();
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new ServletException("Login failed", e);
} finally {
    if (resultSet != null) try { resultSet.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    if (statement != null) try { statement.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
    if (connection != null) try { connection.close(); } catch (SQLException ignore) {}
}

if (login) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("username", userName); // I'd prefer the User object, which you get from DAO, but ala.
    response.sendRedirect("home.jsp"); // Redirect to home page.
} else {
    request.setAttribute("message", "Unknown username/password, try again"); // This sets the ${message}
    request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp").forward(request, response); // Redisplay JSP.
}
```

And add `${message}` to your JSP:

```
<form action="LoginPage" method="POST">
    User name: <input type="text" name="userName" size="20"><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password" size="20">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"> ${message}
</form>
```

Here are some links to learn how to do JSP/Servlet/JDBC properly.

- [Beginning and Intermediate JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)
- [Advanced JSP/Servlet tutorials (with JDBC)](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/msajsp.html)
- [DAO tutorial - How to create a proper data layer](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)
- [DAO tutorial - Using in JSP/Servlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-use-in-jspservlet.html)

Answer (score 1):

toString() for request.getParameter is not required.

You can modify your query to

```
String sql = "SELECT <PASSWORD_CLM> FROM LOGIN WHERE USR_NAME="+userName;


while(rs.next()) 
{ 
   //read the password in pass. 
} 
if(pass !=null && pass.equals(passWord)) 
{ 
  // Code
}
```

Comment: You do need to put the semi colon at the end of the SQL statement even with Prepared statements though.

Comment: @Dean: this is not true. This is only required when you want to pass multiple statements in one query. The semicolon is then the statement separator. Also note that whether it is accepted is DB dependent.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `SELECT PASSWORD from Login` in the sql query
here `PASSWORD` is the column name which contains password in your  database table `LOGIN`

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing problems with the lines:

```
  String sql = "SELECT USR_NAME FROM LOGIN WHERE USR_NAME='userName'";
    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
    String usr = null;
    String pass = null;
```

It should be:

```
String sql = "SELECT * from LOGIN WHERE USR_NAME="+ userName+";";
```

Also check the table name for the login information as you have it as `LOGIN` sure it isn't `login`? 
Also i would avoid writing HTML in the servlet and just let it forward to another JSP. It could just be something simple for now. Saying Logged in.
Dean